# Is it considered in poor taste to post an entire short program to get feedback?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Is it considered in poor taste to post a short program in it's entirety to stackoverflow to get feedback from those with more experience?

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: @Mysticial codereview.stackexchange.com is **only** for requesting review of code that **is already working** (in the sense that it compiles, runs, and generally works the way it was intended to).

Comment: @EliahKagan I'm fully aware of that. But the way I read the question seemed to imply that the code was already working.

Comment: @Mysticial Yeah, I'm not saying you shouldn't have suggested Code Review. It's just that it would be *bad* if lots of people started posting their uncompilable code snippets there.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is indeed unsuitable.

Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions - not complete code reviews.

However, there is a site for that - [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)...

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is **only** for requesting review of code that **is already working** (in the sense that it compiles, runs, and generally works the way it was intended to). ....Isn't it?

Comment: @EliahKagan - Sure. That's what I am getting from the OP - that it is working and they want feedback.